# For each loop conditions causing type mismatch

Tags: vba, excel, loops

When the loop conditions include the entire range of Column F, this codes works just fine:

```
Dim ABnumb As String
Dim cellSkill As Range
Let ABnumb = dayWS.Cells(i1, 2).Value

    For Each cellSkill In skillSheet.Range("F:F")
        If cellSkill.Value = ABnumb Then
            Let skillNumb = cellSkill.Offset(0, -5).Value
            Let skillDelimited = skillDelimited & ";" & skillNumb
        End If
    Next cellSkill
```

But to increase efficiency, I want to limit the loop to the used range. When I change the code to this:

```
For Each cellSkill In skillSheet.UsedRange("F")
```

I get a type mismatch error for this expression:

```
If cellSkill.Value = ABnumb Then
```

I played with changing the two variables' declared data types, but nothing availed.

Is there a way I can use .UsedRange("F")? Or should I just resort to .Range(1, lastRow), where lastRow is already determined by the script?

Also, what happens to the For Each variable cellSkill in the loop? Can I reuse this variable for another For Each loop through cell ranges without trouble?

Answer (score 4):

Use Intersect to trim column F down to the worksheet's .UsedRange property.

```
For Each cellSkill In Intersect(skillSheet.Columns("F"), skillSheet.UsedRange)
    ...
next cellSkill
```

To address your alternative, it should be,

```
with skillSheet
    for each cellSkill in .Range(.cells(1, "F"), .cells(.rows.count, "F").end(xlup))
        ...
    next cellSkill
end with
```

Yes, you can reuse cellSkill in a following For .... Next loop. When you exit this last loop, cellSkill should be `Nothing`.

Comment: Using Intersect produced the same type mismatch error. However, as I thought, the last row method works fine. Does Intersect work for you as you have it written? What might be the cause for my error?

Comment: I used `Debug.Print Intersect(skillSheet.Columns("F"), skillSheet.UsedRange).Address` before the loop and `Debug.Print cellSkill.Address` within the loop. Both came out correct.